# Target/Classes accidentally removed from Java Maven Project in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My Maven project was working fine in IntelliJ. I was writing "How to run the project" in README so I tried to open the project in Eclipse. When I opened it in Eclipse, it did not show src/main/java even though the folder exists. I then removed the project from Eclipse work space (not from the disk).

Now, when I ran the code in IntelliJ again, my `Main.class` and other classes were deleted from `target/classes`, thus producing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

My project tree:

```
Project
    .idea
    src
        main
            java
            resources
        test
    target
        classes (This is where all classes were removed)
    ...
```

I have tried to undo my last `git add` with `git reset -- target`. Of course the error is still there.

How do I restore my `target/classes`?

Comment: By running `mvn compile`?

Comment: Do _not_ mess with Git over this please.  If your class files are missing, just do a Maven build again and they will come back.  You might have done a Maven clean somehow and removed them.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @TimBiegeleisen (see comments), it's working.

If you're in IntelliJ, click `Build > Rebuild Project` then `Run` the project again.